# Dynamic linQ on string array

Tags: arrays, dynamic-linq

I have a string array like this.

```
string[] ColumnArray = new string[] { First story, second data , third way };
```

Following is the linQ query on this array.

```
string query = (from x in ColumnArray 
                           where x.Contains("Story")
                            select x).First();
```

But sometimes the query will be like this.

```
string query = (from x in ColumnArray 
                         where ( x.Contains("Story") || x.Contains("View"))
                         select x).First();
```

That condition should add dynamically. SO how the dynamic LinQ can helps here.

I have written something like this.

```
string dynamiccondition= // some condition.

 var query = (from x in ColumnArray.AsEnumerable().AsQueryable().Where(dynamiccondition).Select(x));
```

// but this is not working.

Any suggestion?

Comment: what condition you try? What you meant not working? it raise exception or not filter?

Comment: condition may be something like this  string dynamiccondition = "x.Contains('Story') ||  x.Contains('view')"; -- > but I am not sure how to write dynamic linQ on string array. What i need is to get the string which contain any of these values(I need to make the condition using dynamic linQ) .

Comment: try see more on [official page](http://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com/documentation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `DynamicLINQ` you can use logical operation like `AND(&&)` and `OR(||)`, so try something like this

```
string dynamiccondition="it.Contains(\"Story\") OR it.Contains(\"View\")"

var query = ColumnArray.AsQueryable()
                       .Where(dynamiccondition);
```